# error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) android

Tags: android, eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>




<LinearLayout




   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   




   android:orientation="vertical"




   android:layout_width="fill_parent"




   android:layout_height="fill_parent">




  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"




  android:layout_height="wrap_content"




  android:text="@string/hello" />




  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 




      android:layout_height="wrap_content"




      android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">



  <EditText android:id="@+id/inNama"



      android:layout_height="wrap_content"



      android:layout_width="100dip" android:inputType="text"></EditText>



  <EditText android:id="@+id/inHobi"



    android:layout_height="wrap_content"



    android:layout_width="100dip"  android:inputType="text"></EditText>



  <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"



      android:id="@+id/btnAdd"



      android:layout_height="wrap_content"



      android:text="@string/btnAddtxt"></Button>



  </LinearLayout>



  <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"



      android:layout_width="match_parent"



      android:id="@+id/tabel_data">



  <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"



      android:layout_width="wrap_content"



      android:layout_height="wrap_content">



  <TextView  android:layout_height="wrap_content"



      android:layout_width="50dip"



      android:text="@string/nomorLabel"



      android:id="@+id/no_id"></TextView>


  <TextView  android:layout_height="wrap_content"



      android:layout_width="100dip"



      android:text="@string/namaLabel"



      android:id="@+id/nama_id"></TextView>



  <TextView android:layout_width="100dip" 



      android:layout_height="wrap_content"



      android:text="@string/hobiLabel"



      android:id="@+id/hobi_id"></TextViewk>



  </TableRow>




  </TableLayout>



  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest you take a quick lesson about xml first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lastline contains an extra k in `TextView` tag....

```
android:id="@+id/hobi_id"></TextView>
```

instead of...

```
android:id="@+id/hobi_id"></TextViewk>
```